# Convert UTF-8 to Traditional Chinese Characters

Tags: iphone, encoding, internationalization, cjk

I can't seem to find good documentation that will allow me to do the following:

I've got a bunch of UTF-8 strings JSON'ed down to my iPhone app and displayed into a UITableView. When the user clicks on an item, I want a UIActionSheet to come up to notify them of the category that they've selected.

---

[image]

---

The problem is that while the Chinese Characters show up in the UITableView without problem, they show up as UTF-8 characters in the UIActionSheet. Is there any way to convert it from UTF-8 into traditional Chinese characters?

I'm trying to do it like this but it's not working:

```
const char *subCatName = [[thirdParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1] UTF8String];
    NSString *subCatSelectedConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:subCatName];       

    NSString *actionSheetTitle = [@"You have selected " stringByAppendingString:subCatSelectedConverted];

    NSString *actionSheetTitleFinal = [actionSheetTitle stringByAppendingString:@", proceed to upload to selected subcategory?"];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionSheetTitleFinal delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed to Upload" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after further investigation this did the trick:

```
NSString *subCatSelectedName = [[thirdParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSString *actionSheetTitle = [@"You have selected '" stringByAppendingString:subCatSelectedName];

        NSString *actionSheetTitleFinal = [actionSheetTitle stringByAppendingString:@"', proceed to upload to selected subcategory?"];

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionSheetTitleFinal delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed to Upload" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

This did the trick:

---

[image]

Comment: Link / image in answer is dead.